# python - sorting floats within elements of an array based on another array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have a data array looks, for example, like:

```
data = [
    [1.4, 2.6, 7.3, 4.2],
    [1.1, 2.0, 6.4, 1.0],
    [5.1, 6.2, 5.3, 9.9]
]
```

and another array with class labels:

```
class_labels = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
```

Each of the class labels corresponds to certain floats in each element of the data array (e.g., class `'a'` corresponds to `1.4` and `7.3` from `data[0]`, `1.1` and `6.4` from `data[1]`, and `5.1` and `5.3` from `data[0]`).

I understand from other posts how I could go about sorting one array based on another array, but is it possible to sort the `class_labels` array alphabetically, also sorting the corresponding floats within each element of the data array?

It's possible I've totally gone about this wrong - if I want to be able to later access certain floats from each element (i.e., only floats corresponding to a given class label), will that be possible?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to sort arrays based on the sort order of another, but I would suggest a dictionary instead as it'll probably be easier to work with. Something like:

```
data_by_class = {label:[] for label in set(class_labels)}
for row in data:
    for idx in range(len(row)):
        data_by_class[class_labels[idx]].append(row[idx])
```

which would result in

```
{ 'a':[1.4, 7.3, 1.1, 6.4, 5.1, 5.3], 'b': [2.6, 4.2, 2.0, 1.0, 6.2, 9.9] }
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's begin with you data

```
In [1]: data = [
   ...:     [1.4, 2.6, 7.3, 4.2],
   ...:     [1.1, 2.0, 6.4, 1.0],
   ...:     [5.1, 6.2, 5.3, 9.9]
   ...: ]
In [2]: labels = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
```

Zip it to merge two arrays into one object

```
In [3]: zip(labels, *data)
Out[3]: 
[('a', 1.4, 1.1, 5.1),
 ('b', 2.6, 2.0, 6.2),
 ('a', 7.3, 6.4, 5.3),
 ('b', 4.2, 1.0, 9.9)]
```

Now sort the result:

```
In [4]: sorted(zip(labels, *data))
Out[4]: 
[('a', 1.4, 1.1, 5.1),
 ('a', 7.3, 6.4, 5.3),
 ('b', 2.6, 2.0, 6.2),
 ('b', 4.2, 1.0, 9.9)]
```

Then unzip it back:

```
In [6]: zip(*sorted(zip(labels, *data)))
Out[6]: 
[('a', 'a', 'b', 'b'),
 (1.4, 7.3, 2.6, 4.2),
 (1.1, 6.4, 2.0, 1.0),
 (5.1, 5.3, 6.2, 9.9)]
```

And finally get the result with an *ugly* oneliner

```
In [7]: [list(x) for x in zip(*sorted(zip(labels, *data)))[1:]]
Out[7]: [[1.4, 7.3, 2.6, 4.2], [1.1, 6.4, 2.0, 1.0], [5.1, 5.3, 6.2, 9.9]]
```

You can split the oneliner  if you wish to make the code more readable

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to organise your data differently, although its a little unclear exactly what you're looking for.

If we assume that you would still like row based data, where each row consists of (possibly multiple) observations of different classes, then you could reorganise your data into a list of dictionaries

```
import itertools
row_dicts = [{k: [x[1] for x in v] 
              for k, v in itertools.groupby(
                  sorted(zip(class_labels, row)), key=lambda x: x[0])}
             for row in data]
```

Now your data appears as:

```
>>> row_dicts
[{'a': [1.4, 7.3], 'b': [2.6, 4.2]},
 {'a': [1.1, 6.4], 'b': [1.0, 2.0]},
 {'a': [5.1, 5.3], 'b': [6.2, 9.9]}]
```

And you can discover eg all observations with label `a` from row `1`

```
>>> row_dicts[1]["a"]
[1.1, 6.4]
```